# bash - getopts in switch case

Tags: bash, shell, arguments, getopts

I'm trying to use getopts inside a switch case loop.
if i use only getopts or only the switch case it's work, however when i combine  those two the getopts dos not trigger.

i have search  a lot but i cat fins any  mention for how to combine them, and problem i missing something stupid so for give me ...

here is the code essence.

```
#!/bin/bash
case $1 in

        ver)
            echo "vesion"
            exit 0
        ;;
        op)
           while getopts ":a" opt; do
                case $opt in
                 a)
                   echo "-a was triggered!" >&2
                 ;;
                \?)
                   echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
                 ;;
                esac
        done
        ;;
esac
```

when i do that

```
# bash -x test.sh op -a
```

i get

```
+ case $1 in
+ getopts :a opt
```

(and without debug i get nothing)

what is that that i missing to combine these two

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a `shift` instruction at the beginning of your `op)` choice, before the call to `getopts`, to eat the `op` argument itself. Else, the first argument that `getopts` will analyze is `op` and it will silently stop (end of options).